# Why does this JavaScript function return: "0:0function toString() { [native code] }"?

Tags: javascript, time, string-formatting

I took the following function from [this site](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=475988&page=970) and plugged it into my code to display a user-friendly time string based on a millisecond argument.

Why does this function not work?

```
    function getTimeFromMillis(millis)
    {

        milliSecs = millis;

        msSecs = (1000)
        msMins = (msSecs * 60)
        msHours = (msMins * 60)
        numHours = Math.floor(milliSecs/msHours)
        numMins = Math.floor((milliSecs - (numHours * msHours)) / msMins)
        numSecs = Math.floor((milliSecs - (numHours * msHours) - (numMins * msMins))/ msSecs)


        if (numSecs < 10){
          numSecs = "0" + numSecs.toString
        }
        if (numMins < 10){
          numMins = "0" + numMins.toString
        }

        resultString = numHours + ":" + numMins + ":" + numSecs     
        return resultString;

    }
```

If I pass it a millisecond value from my calling function I get this:

```
0:0function toString() { [native code] }:0function toString() { [native code] }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot the `()` in your calls to "toString".

*edit* — sorry had to step away for a sec. As @Gareth commented, the references to "toString" are syntactically valid, as they're just references to functions. Thus the *parser* has no problems with your code. What goes wrong is when you implicitly convert those references to strings.

If you just add `()` to each call, it should work a lot better. Or, as that very page you linked to points out a few posts further down, you really don't need `.toString()` at all.

Comment: Specifically, the code `"0" + numMins.toString` is adding a *string* to a *function*. Javascript does this by converting the function into a string, which it does by outputting the source of the function (or, the cryptic `[native code]` for built-in functions)